# Action Script 3. How to get object's name from e.target?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, object, events

I'm developing drag and drop game. I can't get `e.target` name successfully.

I'm using following:

```
private function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (e.target.hitTestObject(e.target.name+"Field")) // here I should get name
    {
        trace(e.target + "Field");
        trace(e.target.name + "Field");
        trace(e.target.label + "Field");
        e.target.x = (e.target).x;
        e.target.y = (e.target).y;
    }
```

Idea is that I have object `Item1` and if It hit `Item1Field` should get success. But for now I can't get `e.target` name correctly. I've used traces for test purpose and It returned following:

```
trace(e.target);
OUTPUT: [object Item1]Field

trace(e.target.name);
OUTPUT: instance55Field

trace(e.target.label);
OUTPUT: undefinedField
```

It should return `Item1Field` have you ideas?

---

In following I add listeners for objects:

```
private function addListeners(... objects):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragObject);
        objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload the FLA file? Try to set `objects[i].mouseChildren = false;`

Comment: Why you need FLA file, don't care what is inside stage. This code was used to get `Instance` name from stage objects by using `e.target.name`, but how to get object's name which added by `addChild` to get `Item1Field` instead of `[object Item1]Field`. Where I need to set `objects[i].mouseChildren = false;` and what It do?

Comment: What is `Item1Field`? It's a Class or a String?

Comment: If it's Class use this code: `Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.target)))`

Comment: It's MovieClip object the same as `Item1` So in properties It shows `Class: Item1Field` I will try to explain. I have for example 2 objects on stage: with `AS Linkage`: `Item1` and `Item1Field` and player need to drag and drop `Item1` to `Item1Field`. I have declared It in AS 3 as following: `var item1:Item1 = new Item1();` and `var item1field:Item1Field = new Item1Field();`

Comment: Ok. I understand. Try: `if (e.target.hitTestObject(this[getQualifiedClassName(e.target) + "Field"]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposed that you have two objects like this :

```
var item1:Item1 = new Item1();
    item1.name = 'item1';
    addChild(item1);

var item1_field:Field = new Field();
    item1_field.name = 'item1_Field';
    addChild(item1_field);
```

So you can do like this to access to your `item1_field` ( named `item1_Field` ) :

```
private function stopDragObject(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var name:String = e.currentTarget.name + '_' + 'Field';

    trace(e.currentTarget.parent[name].name);   // gives : item1_Field
    trace(e.currentTarget.parent[name]);        // gives : [object Field]

    if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(e.currentTarget.parent[name])) 
    {
        // instructions here
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.